# How to get boxplot to give me grouped data from this dataframe

Tags: r

```
#I have a dataframe in R:
unlist.Cells.; sort.Bioreactors_grouped1.; Days1
1   1   CS1 2
2   2   CS1 2
3   3   CS1 2
4   4   CS1 2
5   5   CS1 2
6   2   CS2 2
7   3   CS2 2
8   6   CS2 2
9   8   CS2 2
10  0   CS1 4
11  4   CS1 4
12  5   CS1 4
13  8   CS1 4
14  6   CS1 4
15  6   CS2 4
16  6   CS2 4
17  7   CS2 4
18  10  CS2 4
```

I cant get my code to gime a grouped plot based on my code
Upon writing code I get a box plot

[image]

however it does not seem to have distributed the CS groups correctly across days 2 and 4. Any ideas?

I have a bunch of threads and this works on other dataframes but not this one in particular. I was wondering could anyone tell me why?

```
plot <- ggplot(Data, mapping = aes(x = Days1, y=unlist.Cells., 
                                   fill= sort.Bioreactors_grouped1.)) + 
          geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please try `factor(Days1)`. `ggplot2` sees day as a continuous variable

Comment: Days1 is numeric here. You want it to be a factor. Either change the data.frame or use an argument like `x = as.factor(Days1)`.

Comment: Brilliant, this is why i get for being a noob at dataframes. Thank you both!

Comment: @LinasBaltabarzdisTamošaitis every master begins a noob.